# Question on Picard-Lindelöf theorem proof.

Tags: real-analysis

Here the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) (and it's proof). My problem is that we proved the existence and unicity in the space $(\mathcal C^0([a,b]),\|\cdot \|_\infty )$. My question is 
**Don't we want the existence and uniqueness in $\mathcal C^1([a,b])$ ? and why do we use the norm $\|u\|_\infty =\sup |u|$ ? it's not a norm over $\mathcal C^1([a,b])$ ? is it ?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you want the solution to be in $C^1$ but that is very hard to do directly. The iterative proof works easily in $C^0$ with uniform norm. The point is that because it is a fixed point of the integral equation, the solution is $C^1$ in time!